# Survfit's method for generating the confidence interval of the median survival estimate

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

The `survival` package function `survfit()` calculates a confidence interval for the estimated median survival time.  It seems clear that this interval is calculated as the set of timepoints for which the 95% CI for S_hat(t) contains 0.5, and as such the interval will vary depending on which transformation is used to construct the pointwise 95% CIs.

My question is: I have seen this referred to on various message boards as the Brookmeyer-Crowley method - is this correct?

My thoughts: It seems that the Brookmeyer-Crowley method is related to the above method in that it constructs the interval as the set of points for which we do not reject the null hypothesis that S_hat(t) = 0.5, but that test is a sign test, and so stricly speaking, while related, the method `survfit()` uses is not the Brookmeyer-Crowley method, but rather a pseudo-Brookmeyer-Crowley method.

Answer (score 1):

The 'generalised sign test' in Brookmeyer & Crowley's [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2530286) rejects if $\hat S-1/2$ is greater than a specified multiple of the Greenwood standard error estimate. That's what the construction in `survfit` does.

It's a 'generalised sign test' in the sense that it generalises the sign test for the median, not in the sense that it uses signs and does some different thing with them.

Comment: So the `survfit` default method can be correctly called the Brookmeyer & Crowley method?

Comment: Yes, it's the same method.

Comment: Having looked into it further, I don't think this is correct.  It's similar, in that that it builds intervals for median survival as the set of timepoints that fail to reject a null hypothesis that survival = 0.5, but the test is different.  My reason for thinking this is that I used the `quantileKM()` function from the `biostatUZH` and the results it gives are different to those from `survfit()`.  The `biostatUZH` package documentation states "Computation of confidence intervals is done according to Brookmeyer, R. and Crowley, J. (1982)"

Comment: Furthermore, the median survival CI in `survfit()` changes as you alter the confidence interval type (for suvival estimates), whereas the B-C method, which is based on a single test (modified sign test), would not vary.

Comment: @fair21comic the Brookmeyer-Crowley method is for using the set of point-wise confidence intervals (CIs) for survival _fractions_ to estimate CI for the median (or other quantile) survival _time_. If the method for estimating the original survival-fraction CI changes, then the Brookmeyer-Crowley estimates will change, too. The default survival-fraction CI type for `survfit()` is "log"; that for `quantileKM()` is "log-log". I recall that the original Brookmeyer-Crowley paper might have used even a different survival-fraction CI type. I suspect that explains the differences you found.